# Why doesn't the Visual Studio Compiler do loop unrolling with my Mersenne-Twister implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mersenne-twister

I am currently working on my own [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) implementation in C++. The algorithm involves calling the following function several times:

```
void twistIteration(uint32_t i)
{
    uint32_t x = (mt[i] & MASK_UPPER) + (mt[(i + 1) % N] & MASK_LOWER);

    uint32_t xA = x >> 1;

    if (x & 1)
    {
        xA ^= A;
    }

    mt[i] = mt[(i + M) % N] ^ xA;
}
```

Note that N, M and MASK_UPPER are template arguments, so they are known at compile time. I call this function inside another function:

```
void twist()
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        twistIteration(i);
    }

    index = 0;
}
```

Generating 128.000.000 random numbers with this algorithm takes roughly 0.95 seconds on my machine. However, I found a way to significantly speed up the algorithm by changing the twist function a little:

```
void twist()
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        twistIteration(i);
    }

    twistIteration(N - 1);

    index = 0;
}
```

In other words, I unroll the last iteration of the loop so that the expressions `(i + 1) % N` and `(i + M) % N` can be calculated at compile time. The same amount of random numbers now only takes 0,60 seconds, which is a huge improvement.
My question is: why doesn’t the compiler do this for me? I compiled with the default VS2017 release mode and set “fast code optimization but bigger code” to true. Is there some flag that I am missing or is this just some strange behavior of the Visual Studio compiler?

Comment: You seem to be asking why the compiler doesn't produce the most optimal machine code for your program. Well, that's because doing so is _hard_ - maybe VC++ can't see this particular optimisation. You cannot expect _any_ specific optimisations to be performed on your code.

Comment: What is the exact command-line for `cl` that you're using? Do you get the desired optimizations if you use a different toolchain like `gcc` or `clang`?

Comment: I don't expect any specific optimization to be done by the compiler, but basic loop unrolling should be expected, especially when some expressions are known at compile time.

Comment: "t basic loop unrolling should be expected," Says who? I've written a couple of C compilers and neither of them did loop  unrolling. If the compiler doesn't do the optimisation you want, use another compiler that does.

Comment: If you share a compilable version, we could say more, I think. Now, we don't see the whole picture. Especially the value of `N` could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on compiler optimization to handle things like this can be tricky. Your best bet would be to experiment with different flags to see if you can get an appreciable difference.

That said, I would try significantly increasing the number of elements you're generating. It's very possible this 0.35 seconds is just variance that could depend on a variety of other factors. Try stress testing for something that takes a minute (or longer) to run and see if the difference is still as dramatic.

Answer (score 0):

It may resist unrolling larger loops even with thay setting.

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
inline auto index_over(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)(std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Is>{}...);
  }
}
template<std::size_t N>
inline auto index_upto(std::integral_constant<std::size_t,N> ={}){
  return index_over(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
template<class F>
inline auto foreacher(F&&f){
  return [&](auto&&...args){
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,(void(
      f(decltype(args)(args))
    ),0)...};
  };
}
```

now

```
auto index=index_upto<N>();
index(foreacher([&](auto I){
  twistIteration(I);
));
```

is force loop unrolled to an insane degree (it would take a smart compiler to reroll that loop).

Apologies for any typos, on phone.  You can google `site:stackoverflow.com yakk` plus `index_upto` tomfind variants with possibly fewer typos.